# How To Synchronize Directories in two different external hard disks?

Tags: fedora-20

I have few big folders "cosmo_sim_9", "cosmo_sim_10".... in one of my external hard disk, and a old copy of this on another external hard disk. I want to Synchronize old directories with the new one(recursively), but without overwriting already existing files(for saving time). How can I do this this? My os is Fedora 20.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Sorry... I am using Fedora 20

Comment: @RSJohn the dd command should do the trick. http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=252973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` is pretty much the default program to synchronize files between directories. Try a command along the lines of:

```
rsync -r --update --progress --dry-run
```

That will tell you what would be copied and what wouldn't. The `--update` command only copies files when the source is newer than the destination. If it looks correct, then take off the `--dry-run` option. If it's not right, check the man page for `rsync` to see what I did wrong.

[Here is the man page for `rsync`.](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html)